# How to maintain the context in javascript async call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, moodle, yui

I'm working with moodle version 3.2, and i want to catch all the ajax requests and delay them. I can catch them, but i can't maintain the context in which they were called.

Example: I have 2 javascript files, `accessManager.js` and `filepicker.js`.
The `accessManager.js` is included in all HTML files.

My accessManager.js contains:

```
function myFunction(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout( function () {
      var r = confirm("Ajax Request!");
      if (r) {
        resolve(true);
      }
      else {
        reject(false);
      }
    }, 3000);
  });
}
```

and `filepicker.js` (the important part,the ajax call) contains

```
myFunction().then(function(){
  Y.io(api, cfg);
 });
```

The problem lies in the ajax call that is done in a different context, and return some errors. How can i keep the ajax call context?? The expected behavior would be filepicker -> call myFunction async to delay the ajax call -> return to filepicker context and make the call.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: wich error? wich context (wanted/is there)?

Comment: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null".
Basically the context, when returning from the delayed ajax call is not the same as the call not delayed. Leading to a getAttribute() form a null form.

Comment: theres no .getAttribute() call in your code, so we cant help you...

Comment: Sorry, but in my opinion you do not need to know that. I only want to know how can i keep the context of filepicker.js when returning from myFunction call, since it is not happening this way.

Comment: the context is *window* or some other *global* in this case...